# Find $\int_{|z|=1} f(z) d z$, when $f(z)=(z \sin z) /(z+2)+\bar{z}$

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-integration, cauchy-integral-formula

Find $\int_{|z|=1} f(z) d z$, when $f(z)=(z \sin z) /(z+2)+\bar{z}$

$f(z)$ looks like analytic function. If it is analytic, then by Cauchy-Theorem, integration will be zero. I tried to show Cauchy-Riemann equations by using $$\frac{\partial f}{\partial \bar{z}}=0,$$
I got $$\frac{\partial }{\partial \bar{z}} ((z \sin z) /(z+2)+\bar{z}) = 1 + \left(\frac{\partial }{\partial \bar{z}} (z \sin z) /(z+2)\right)$$

I don't know how to proceed.

Since $|z| = 1$, I replaced $z = 1 / \bar{z}$ and $z/(z+2) = 1 / (2\bar{z} + 1)$, but I am not sure if it is the right way.

Comment: only replace the last $z^*=1/z$. then you can use Cauchy's theorem, because you'll be left with a function with one part being holomorphic in the unit disc and the other part having a pole. the error you're making is you're making the substitution twice so you once again have things in terms of z and $z^*$

Comment: Nop, you can't make that this replacement just like that, without further justification, since then you get $$\frac{ z\sin z}{z+2+\frac1z}=\frac{z^2\sin z}{(z+1)^2}$$ and thus you have a singularity on the curve $\;|z|=1\;$ over which you want to integrate...

Comment: so, after replacing, 1/z is analytic. What do u mean by having pole? And I think (z sin z)/(z+2) will have pole, right?

Comment: You have $\;(z+1)^2\;$ in the denominator, which vanishes at $\;z=-1\;$ , on the unit circle...In fact that singularity is there all the time, whether you make that repalcement or not. It is just that after the replacement it is crystal clear it is there.

Comment: @DonAntonio I think you got the question wrong. \bar{z} is not on the denominator.

Comment: @Snowball Well, I see then...perhaps you should try to write mathematics in this site with MathJax, as directed in the site when we sign up ...

Comment: Are there any suggested ideas for the problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try this,

$$\oint_{|z|=1}\left(\frac{z\sin z}{z+2}+\overline z\right)dz=\oint_{|z|=1}\overline z\,dz$$

and now write (by mere definition of complex line integral, with parametrization and etc.)

$$\;z=e^{it}\;,\;\;0\le t\le 2\pi\implies dz=ie^{it}dt$$

so the remaining integral equals
0
$$\int_0^{2\pi}e^{-it}\,i\,e^{it}\,dt=i\int_0^{2\pi}dt=2\pi i$$

Observe that the first part of the first integral (the first summand's integral)  is zero since that is an analytic function on the unit closed disk.

Comment: Thanks! Sorry for the confusion in problem statement